# How can I export console on HTML page onto a text file?

Tags: javascript, html, file-processing

For a HTML page we have produced with JavaScript, we would like to export the output on the console into a text file as it is updated so we can use in on a Java application.

This has to be done automatically every time the console is updated, and not manually.

This has to work with all browsers. All applications are local.

How would it be possible to do this?

Comment: Not really a duplicate (Not yet at least). The other thread is about Chrome console specifically. Other browsers also have consoles built into them and OP did not specify if he's looking to target all/specific ones.

Comment: Is your Java application on server side or on client side?

Comment: @Constantiner `This has to work with all browsers` so I suspect client-side ;)

Comment: *every time the console is updated*. Does this mean you want **all** of the console outputs? Like the ~hundred I got just by navigating to this page, including requests and CSS parsing errors? Not possible. Only the ones that do pass through one of `window.console` methods? Override them. Only the ones you want to debug? Store them directly, why use the console?